# Change CSS If date inside a div is older than 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a wallboard to display service calls.

I want to change the background of the wallboard to a certain colour (e.g. red) when the date within the 'date logged' is older than 24 hours, I've not got much experience with jQuery and am struggling to get this working!

Hope this makes sense!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Superslides - A fullscreen slider for jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $conn=odbc_connect('wallboard_data','','');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM [data$]";
    $rs2=odbc_exec($conn,$sql2);
    if (!$rs2) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }
    echo " <div id=\"slides\">
    <ul class=\"slides-container\">";
    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs2)) {
        $date=odbc_result($rs2,"Date");
        $customer=odbc_result($rs2,"Customer");
        $region=odbc_result($rs2,"Region");
        $sla=odbc_result($rs2,"SLA");
        $machine_fault=odbc_result($rs2,"Machine Fault");
        $machine_type=odbc_result($rs2,"Machine Type");
        $cust_updated_date=odbc_result($rs2,"Customer Updated");

        $ops_mngr=odbc_result($rs2,"Ops manager Informed");
        $rgm_informed=odbc_result($rs2,"RGM Informed");
        echo "<li><div class=\"container\">Date logged: <div class=\"date\"><strong>$date</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "Customer Name: <div class=\"customer\"><strong>$customer</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "Region: <div class=\"region\"><strong>$region</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "SLA: <div class=\"sla\"><strong>$sla</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "Machine Fault: <div class=\"machine-fault\"><strong>$machine_fault</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "Machine Type: <div class=\"machine-type\"><strong>$machine_type</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "Customer Last Updated: <div class=\"customer-updated-date\"><strong>$cust_updated_date</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "Operations Manager Informed: <div class=\"ops\"><strong>$ops_mngr</strong></div><br/>";
        echo "RGM Informed: <div class=\"rgm\"><strong>$rgm_informed</strong></div></div></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    odbc_close($conn);
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#slides').superslides({
        hashchange: true,
        play: 5000
    });
    $('#slides').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).superslides('stop');
        console.log('Stopped')
    });
    $('#slides').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).superslides('start');
        console.log('Started')
    });
});
</script>
<script>
    $(".container .sla:contains('')")
        .closest("body").css("background-color" , "#590f0f");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) how to get the current date. 2) how to get the text in a div. 3) how to convert string to date. 4) how to compare dates. 5) how to change css using js. Everything is already answered. You just need to make some effort and move 4ward 1step at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Date.parse`, `jQuery.each` and `setInterval` to check your list's items' dates periodically.
Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9EUGf/2/

It may be a little messy, but should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Michal that's perfect. I've implemented this and it's working!